# Is it possible to get data from trading page via certain script?

Tags: automation, trading, tradingview-api

E.g. I would like to get the open-high-low-close price over a certain period of time on this page:

https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=BITTREX%3ABTCUSD

(The values are at the top of the chart area, right next to the label "Bitcoin / U.S. Dollar 1D BITTREX".)

Are there any ways of getting such data in an automated way?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSdvp.png)you dont need a script, In the menu button there is a Export data icon.
This exports 300 periods of the selected data by you.

Comment: Where is the menu button? I can not recognize it from your screenshot.